# How can I achieve smooth drawing in QT similar to Onenote or Goodnotes?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, drawing, antialiasing

I am trying to create an inking mechanic like the one in Onenote or goodnotes using QT.
The idea is creating a simple white canvas and a drawing mechanic. I've actually achieved these both, but the lines I draw with the app are too pixelated and not smooth.

Therefore I tried to use smoothing methods of QTPainter library.

```cpp
void Canvas::penSettings() {
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 10, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap, Qt::RoundJoin));
}
```

Image (left one is QT right one is Onenote):
[image: Comparison between mine and Onenote]

As shown in the image, it didn't turn out as I expected, and now I find myself stuck with these questions: Are Qt libraries enough to achieve this, or should I consider using other libraries like OpenGL or Skia? Do I need to create custom drawing algorithms, or is the issue arising due to antialiasing?

Comment: Both images are anti-aliased. The comparison is not good, since one is blue on white and the other is white on black. From what I can see, the Onenote lines might be using some kind of smoothing/spline logic to iron out wobbly strokes. They also appear to support pressure sensitivity/stroke width whereas yours doesn't. These things alone may contribute greatly to a more jagged appearance.

Comment: Another thing I notice is your pixels are bigger. This might be a high-DPI compatibility setting or something, which results in your application's output being scaled.